# Drop in the Kafka consume rate

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are working with python-kafka library and we upgraded the Kafka cluster to 2.2 from 0.10.2 
We got a lower rate of consuming (rate of poll).

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: Not so long ago, I tested a similar update (from 0.10.2.0 to 2.0.1) and found a significant decrease in overhead data transfer during the network, but no degradation was noticed.

Therefore, it seems to me that you need to describe your problem in more detail, in particular, attach the code.

Comment: We didnt change our client code or Kafka client version we just upgrade the brokers because of that I try to understand why 2 same consumer version got different consume rate @Andrey

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following action: `pip install crc32c` resolved the performance issue in the python client.

REF: https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/a6be21e7b3/docs/install.rst